# amcl_pose does not publish

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, amcl-pose, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following my last question, [No laser scan recieved](http://answers.ros.org/question/126111/no-laser-scan-received/) still nothing is published by **/amcl_pose** and **roswtf** out is:

```
WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /amcl:
   * /initialpose


Found 5 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/amcl] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/play_1391569963540725368] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/map_server_1391569952840022254] raised an error: 
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /amcl->/amcl (/tf)
 * /play_1391569963540725368->/amcl (/base_scan)
 * /play_1391569963540725368->/map_server_1391569952840022254 (/clock)
 * /play_1391569963540725368->/amcl (/clock)
 * /map_server_1391569952840022254->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /amcl->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /play_1391569963540725368->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /play_1391569963540725368->/amcl (/tf)
 * /play_1391569963540725368->/play_1391569963540725368 (/clock)
```

What's the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126306/amcl_pose-does-not-publish/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL is probably waiting for an initial pose. There are two ways to do this: using RVIZ, or using the parameter server:

- [This tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack) shows how to send an initial pose using RVIZ
- you can set the pose via parameters using the amcl parameters initial_pose_x, initial_pose_y, initial_pose_a (see http://wiki.ros.org/amcl for a description of the parameters)

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-30**:
@fergs, I have the same problem, when I do "rostopic echo /amcl_pose", there is no messages!!!! I try rviz to set the initial pose, then we get the co-ordinate from rxconsole output..Is there any way to calculate robot position by listening to some topic?

**Comment by [yasamin](https://answers.ros.org/users/14581/yasamin/) on 2014-05-23**:
hi,i have the same problem,when i use rostopic echo /amcl_pose  give me these warning:

WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?

do you solve your problem?